# Query Not Like returning odd results

Tags: sql, string, select, where-clause, sql-like

Simple Query that I am stumped on. I am trying to filter out jobs that end in `4120`and so forth. When I run this query

```
select Job.Job, Job.Status from Job 
    Where(Job.Job Not Like '%4120'
          And Job.Job Not Like '%4235'
          And Job.Job Not Like '%4236'
          And Job.Job Not Like '%5910'
          And Status = 'Active' OR Status = 'Complete') 
    Order By Job.Job
```

I Get these results

```
    Job         Status
    01-19-4120  Complete
    01-19-4235  Complete
    01-19-5910  Complete
    02-19-4120  Complete
    02-19-4235  Complete
    02-19-4236  Complete
    02-19-5910  Complete
    03-07-4120  Complete
    03-19-4120  Complete
    03-19-4235  Complete
    03-19-5910  Complete
    04-19-4120  Complete
    04-19-4160  Complete
```

Is there something wrong with my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a logical prescendence problem. I highly suspect that you should be surrounding the `OR`ed conditions with parentheses, as follows:

```
Job.Job Not Like '%4120'
And Job.Job Not Like '%4235'
And Job.Job Not Like '%4236'
And Job.Job Not Like '%5910'
And (Status = 'Active' OR Status = 'Complete')
```

Explanation: since logical operator `OR` has lower prescendence than `AND`, your `WHERE` conditions, as they are, are actually equivalent to:

```
(
    Job.Job Not Like '%4120'
    And Job.Job Not Like '%4235'
    And Job.Job Not Like '%4236'
    And Job.Job Not Like '%5910'
    And Status = 'Active' 
) OR Status = 'Complete'
```

This allows any record whose `Status` is `'Complete'`, regardless of the value of `Job`, which is not what you want.

Also, please note that it should be possible to simplify these conditions by using a string function instead of `Not Like`s and an `in` condition instead of `Or`. Assuming that your RDBMS supports `right()`:

```
right(Job.Job, 4) not in ('4120', '4235', '4236', '5910') 
and Status in ('Complete', 'Active')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation. My next question was going to be how to simplify but you answered that as well. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need parenthesis around your `Status = 'Active' OR Status = 'Complete'` because right now your query executes as:

```
WHERE (Job.Job Not Like '%4120'
          And Job.Job Not Like '%4235'
          And Job.Job Not Like '%4236'
          And Job.Job Not Like '%5910'
          And Status = 'Active') OR (Status = 'Complete')
```

So you will get all records where `Status = 'Complete'` regardless of `Job.Job`. To solve this try adding parenthesis around your status check:

```
Where(Job.Job Not Like '%4120'
      And Job.Job Not Like '%4235'
      And Job.Job Not Like '%4236'
      And Job.Job Not Like '%5910'
      And (Status = 'Active' OR Status = 'Complete'))
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a brackets problem. By including the OR within the brackets, your saying "get me all the things that match these strings and have a status of active or have a status of complete - the OR will match records that don't match your other criteria.

```
select Job.Job, Job.Status from Job 
    Where(Job.Job Not Like '%4120'
          And Job.Job Not Like '%4235'
          And Job.Job Not Like '%4236'
          And Job.Job Not Like '%5910')
    And (Status = 'Active' OR Status = 'Complete') 
Order By Job.Job
```

Answer (score 1):

if sql server Try this:

```
select Job.Job, Job.Status from Job 
    Where right(rtrim(Job.Job),4) Not in ('4120','4235','4236','5910')
          And Status = 'Active' OR Status = 'Complete') 
    Order By Job.Job
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need parentheses if you use `in`:

```
Where Job.Job Not Like '%4120' and
      Job.Job Not Like '%4235' and
      Job.Job Not Like '%4236' and
      Job.Job Not Like '%5910' and
      Status in ('Active', 'Complete')
```

Or, if your databases support `left()` as a string function:

```
where left(Job.Job, 4) not in ('4120', '4235', '4236', '5910') and
      Status in ('Active', 'Complete')
```